# Convert single row (name, start date, end date) to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple rows of data with 3 columns (name, start date, end date) and I would like to convert it to one row per day.

I've tried recording a macro (insert n rows) by recording it, but I'm having trouble getting it to loop.

[image: what i have]

[image: what i would like]

Comment: How is the `date` value determined in the middle output row?

Comment: What's `name 1, date`? is that current date? Adding to @braX comment, please show examples of your sheet and example of expected sheet

Comment: @TomBrunberg.. great minds and all of that :)

Comment: is this more helpful?

Comment: First loop through the names (`for name=1 to numNames` for example). Then do an inner loop for `d=start to end`. Then use counters to fill in the correct cells. Basically, you need to read up on loops, then come back when you get stuck and we'll help (although someone is bound to write the code for you in a few minutes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two worksheets, and using Sheet1 as Source and Sheet2 as destination, the following will do what you expect it to, by using a nested For Loop:

```
Sub Process_Dates()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required

LastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A, from Source worksheet

For i = 2 To LastRow
    strName = wsSource.Cells(i, "A").Value
    StartD = wsSource.Cells(i, "B").Value
    EndD = wsSource.Cells(i, "C").Value
    xDays = DateDiff("d", StartD, EndD)
    'get the number of days between Start Date and End Date
    For x = 0 To xDays
    'loop through the number of days between Start and End
        NextRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'get the next available row on Destination worksheet
        wsDestination.Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = strName
        wsDestination.Cells(NextRow, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", x, StartD)
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If instead of moving the data into another worksheet, what you want is to insert the rows into the same worksheet then the following will achieve your desired result:

```
Sub Process_Dates()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
i = 2
'set variable to iterate through rows starting with Row 2
While i <= LastRow
    strName = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
    StartD = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    EndD = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
    xDays = DateDiff("d", StartD, EndD)
    'get the number of days between Start Date and End Date
    For x = 1 To xDays
    'loop through the number of days between Start and End
        ws.Rows(i + x).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        'get the next available row on Destination worksheet
        ws.Cells(i + x, 1).Value = strName
        ws.Cells(i + x, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", x, StartD)
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        'increment LastRow as new row has been inserted
    Next x
    i = (i + xDays) + 1
    'increment the i variable to go to the next row to split
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` available in Excel 2010+
This can all be done using the GUI (except for entering the formula for the custom column)

- From Table/Range
- Set the data type for the date columns to `whole number`
- Add a custom column consisting of the series of numbers from `Start` to `End` as a list

  - `={[Start]..[End]}`
- Extract into rows
- Delete the Start and End Columns
- Set the data type to Date

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Start", Int64.Type}, {"End", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Dates", each {[Start]..[End]}),
    #"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Dates"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Dates",{"Start", "End"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Dates", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]